# Find AD Users Who Belong to More Than One Group in a Particular OU

Tags: active-directory

We have an OU of "People Groups" - is there a way to find users who belong to more than one of the People Groups in that OU only?

Preferably with AD Manager, but Powershell will work, too... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very lightly tested. Should be any account that is in more than one group.

```
$members = (Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=AccessGroup,dc=company,dc=com" -filter * |
 Get-ADGroupMember)
$members_2=$members |  select -Unique
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $members_2 -DifferenceObject $members
```

Comment: The `-Recursive` switch is missing from [Get-ADGroupMember](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx). Without it you won't know nested group membership.

Answer (score 0):

In AD Users and Computers, right click on your domain and go to Find...
Go to the Advanced tab,
Select "Field" then hover to users, then select Member Of...
The value will need to be the distinguished name of the group (IE: CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local) Make sure for folders you use CN= and for OUs you use OU=.

Select the Member Of... for each group you want to find the members that match and click Find Now.

If you don't type the DN correctly, it will not work. Best way to get the right DN is to go to the properties of the group and attributes tab, look for the "distinguished name" property and copy it to a notepad for reference.

Comment: Thanks, so would I have to do this for each group within the "People Groups" OU?  There are dozens...

Comment: In that case, a powershell command will likely need to be used. I thought you were looking for people that were in two or more different groups together.

Comment: To follow up on this, there is a tool I've used called "ManageEngine AD Manager" that gives you a 30 day trial or free mode to run the report you want. It's a great tool and would automate these reports.